# How to fix Intel DRI crashes when playing video full screen?

Tags: debian, video, intel-graphics

When playing video in Orion, I get an error and an orion segfault like:

```
Failed to open BO for returned DRI2 buffer (1920x1080, dri2 back buffer, named x)
This is likely a bug in the X Server that will lead to a crash soon.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[...] in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
[...]
```

This segfault happens occasionally in normal windowed playback, and almost immediately in full screen mode playback.

I'm using Debian 8 (jessie) with Gnome 3 on an ASUS laptop which supports hybrid graphics, but I'm sticking with the Intel graphics if possible to reduce power consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar error behaviour has been reported on Intel graphics hardware with a variety of software that uses DRI. [There is an upstream bug report on freedesktop.org.](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84372) Someone noted on there that this issue is fixed with the `2.99.917-2~bpo8+1 0` version of `xserver-xorg-video-intel` in the `jessie-backports` repository.  Updating to it fixed the problem (instructions below).

Note that my laptop has an Intel wireless NIC with firmware from the non-free `firmware-iwlwifi` package, and since the change prompted a kernel upgrade, to maintain connectivity, I made sure to add the `non-free` package index and upgrade `firmware-iwlwifi` also.

1. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Add the line `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free`
3. Save and exit
4. Run `sudo apt-get update`
5. Run `sudo apt-get upgrade -t jessie-backports xserver-xorg-video-intel`
6. Run `sudo apt-get upgrade -t jessie-backports firmware-iwlwifi`
7. Restart Linux.

If you can't or won't do this upgrade for whatever reason, there are some other reported workarounds on [the upstream bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84372).